# Forced Bing redirect

Tags: google-chrome, redirection, bing, microsoft

I use Google Chrome on my work computer and my personal one. Like a month ago I started to notice a weird behaviour, when I was using google to search something. If i changed the search criteria google redirects to bing. That means when I change the search phrase not in the URL bar but in the search bar of the page itself. It is super annoying.

Here is what I know. It is not a malware. I checked with multiple anti malware programs and contacted officals in my company. Everything came back as not a malware. The only connection between my work computer and personal one is my google chrome account. Today I uninstalled an Edge runtime app on my work computer, I dont remember the name exactly. It solved the issue, but on my personal computer I dont have that. When it redirects to bing it showed me i was logged in with my work microsoft account on my work computer, but on my personal computer I dont have a microsoft account.

Please help me this is driving me crazy. If your answer is it is a malware or that my preferences are setup incorrectly, then you are wrong.

Comment: Have you checked Chrome's extensions/addons?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Of course and all my extensions are clean.